# Header unset Set-Cookie is not working for existing cookies in httpd.conf file

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I want to remove Set-Cookie : 'some cookie details' from the web server http response in that case I used below content to remove it

```
Header unset Set-Cookie
```

But this works properly if have newly added cookie there and it does not works with existing cookies I am seeing in http response.

For Example: If I use below content

```
Header add Set-Cookie "SomeCookie='SomeValue'"
Header unset Set-Cookie
```

It removes the above newly added cookie but not existing cookies. Does anybody know how to remove the existing cookie from http response of apache web server

Comment: Tried with `Header always unset Set-Cookie` already?

Comment: Yes but that also not worked for me actually my Apache web server version is 1.3

Comment: Apache 1.3? Are you kidding? Just go ahead an upgrade.